# Python: WindowsError when creating folder with os.mkdir and using square brackets

Tags: python, windows, directory, mkdir

On Windows, when I tried to create the following folder:

```
    os.mkdir('H:\\__ Photos\\____Photos to be sorted\\[ Photo sorting process ]\\_NEW\\__PROC_PHOTOS\\1. Original CRW')
```

I got the error:

> WindowsError: [Error 3] **The system cannot find the path specified**: 'H:\__ Photos\____Photos to be sorted\[ Photo sorting process ]\_NEW\__PROC_PHOTOS\1. Original CRW'

"_NEW" folder already existed, it was the current working directory. Then I tried to use single backslashes:

```
os.mkdir('H:\__ Photos\____Photos to be sorted\[ Photo sorting process ]\_NEW\__PROC_PHOTOS\1. Original CRW')
```

> WindowsError: [Error 123] **The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**: 'H:\__ Photos\____Photos to be sorted\[ Photo sorting process ]\_NEW\__PROC_PHOTOS\x01. Original CRW'

So the "\1" got converted into "\x01". Escaping this particular backslash resulted in the [Error 3] error, as before.

Making the string a string literal:

```
os.mkdir(r'H:\__ Photos\____Photos to be sorted\[ Photo sorting process ]\_NEW\__PROC_PHOTOS\1. Original CRW')
```

produced the same error:

> WindowsError: [Error 3] **The system cannot find the path specified**: 'H:\__ Photos\____Photos to be sorted\[ Photo sorting process ]\_NEW\__PROC_PHOTOS\1. Original CRW'

Then:

```
os.mkdir("H:\[ Photo sorting process ]\\NEW")
```

was bad ("[ Photo sorting process ]" didn't exist), but:

```
os.mkdir("H:\[ Photo sorting process ]")
os.mkdir("H:\[ Photo sorting process ]\\NEW")
```

was good. Does it mean that I can only create 1 level of subdirectories? Is there any other way? I want to pass the path as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.makedirs` instead of `os.mkdir`. From the documentation:

> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.